# Using Truncated Poisson in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, poisson

Withe help of @ Welcome to Stack Overflow, I managed to truncate the Poisson distribution using upper limit.When I used the function so called **truncated Poisson**, which is user defined function, it worked with single value entry, which I have shown in the code below:

```
import scipy.stats as sct
import pandas as pd
def truncated_Poisson(mu, max_value, size):
    temp_size = size
    while True:
        temp_size *= 2
        temp = sct.poisson.rvs(mu, size=temp_size)
        truncated = temp[temp <= max_value]
        if len(truncated) >= size:
            return truncated[:size]

mu = 2.5
max_value = 10
print(truncated_Poisson(mu, max_value, 1))
```

Unfortunately, I threw me an error when I applied it in the data frame as follow:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['Name'] = ['A','B','C','D','E']
data ['mu']  = [0.5,1.2,2,2.5,2.8]
max_value = 5
size = 1 
data ['Pos'] =  truncated_Poisson(data.mu,max_value,size = 1)
```

The error statement is

```
ValueError: size does not match the broadcast shape of the parameters.
```

Can anyone advise me how to use that function in dataframe?

Thanks

Zep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to call `truncated_Poisson` with the same parameter and each of the `mu` from the data. You can do this for example by using `.apply`:

```
data['Pos'] = data.mu.apply(lambda mu: truncated_Poisson(mu, max_value, size=1))

>>> data
  Name   mu  Pos
0    A  0.5  [0]
1    B  1.2  [0]
2    C  2.0  [3]
3    D  2.5  [4]
4    E  2.8  [3]
```

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your advice. I will apply it to my dataframe.

Comment: Hi @w-m, May I know how to remove the square bracket in Pos?

Comment: Hi I got it. I just convert it to int.